# Python Error: unresolved import 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'Python(unresolved-import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

`from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential`

`from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout`

This is the error that it is showing on the screen. What should I do with it to get rid of the error?

> unresolved import 'tensorflow.python.keras.models'Python(unresolved-import)

Currently using:

- Python 3.8.6 (version)
- tensorflow 1.8.0 (version)
- mac OS 10.15.6,

Comment: Add some details of tensorflow's version and your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change import way.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

or

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: There is still an error that said :

```unresolved import 'keras.layers'Python(unresolved-import)```